# Problem with QSignalMapper and QAction never triger the Slot

Tags: c++, qt

Hi i try to bind slot with argument to QAction triggered SIGNAL
i have this code ,the context menu working great . BUT the OpenPublishWin never triggered .

```
void MyApp::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint& pos) // this is a slot
{
    QString groupID;
    QPoint globalPos = ui.treeView_mainwindow->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QModelIndex modelIndx = ui.treeView_mainwindow->indexAt(pos);
    groupID = modelIndx.model()->index(modelIndx.row(),0,modelIndx.parent()).data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
 QMenu myMenu;
  OpenPublishAction = new QAction(tr("Send"), this);
 myMenu.addAction(OpenPublishAction);

 connect(OpenPublishAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),m_SignalMapper, SLOT(map()) );
 m_SignalMapper->setMapping(OpenPublishAction,groupID);
 connect(m_SignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(OpenPublishWin(QString)));

    QAction* selectedItem = myMenu.exec(globalPos);

}
void MyApp::OpenPublishWin(QString gid)
{
 WRITELOG(gid)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the Qt docs for [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html) (assuming that is what you're using based on the question title) states that the parameter for the mapped signal is const QString&. I can't recall if the parameter needs to be exact in this case for the connection but it may be a factor.

Additionally, double check that your connects are being made by wrapping them in an assert or some form of verify. Qt will also print out to the console if a connection cannot be made.

Comment: NEVER wrap connections in assert! and newer wrap into assert any code doing some work, just checks. use verify instead.

Comment: If you know what you're doing and are just debugging the assert should be fine. However I know what you mean as I debugged something relying on logic inside assert just this very week.

Comment: well, assert is fine until you forget to remove it)) which will happen sooner or later...

Comment: Yes and knowing that we are all idiots at some point it is probably a good idea to just use a verify and never use an assert for this type of thing. Point made!

Comment: there is no Q_VERIFY macro, but i wrote one for that purposes...

`#ifdef _DEBUG
#define Q_VERIFY(x) Q_ASSERT(x)
#else
#define Q_VERIFY(x) (void)x
#endif`